# AngularJs AJAX error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

In a typical AJAX call,what is the way to make the error handling more meaningful.
A template code as below does not help in conveying anything.
How do we decipher the exception better?

```
<script>
var nameapp=angular.module('countryListApp',[]);
nameapp.controller('CountryListCtrl',function($scope,$http){
     var responsePromise = $http.get("/catalog/countries.json");
     responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config){$scope.countries=data; });
     responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("AJAX has failed"); 
    }); 

});
```

Comment: you could create your own `httpInterceptor` that will have watch on each request

Comment: that's horrible to read. Why do you need variables and not just chain the methods? Far easier to read when chained. Also not hard to create a common error handler for many requests and pass it as reference

Answer (score 1):

I use `$httpProvider.interceptors` for this, in your configuration you can set up global error handling. For most of my stuff `MyHttpErrorHandler` would result in a toast.

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider )
{
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
      return {


        // optional method
        'response': function(response) {
          return response;
        },

        // optional method
       'responseError': function(rejection) {

            // window.informUser('Error '+rejection.status +': ' +rejection.config.url);
            if(rejection.status === 0)
            {

                if(window.isInWrapper)
                {
                    //Logout if in an app;
                    window.location.href='ios:logout';
                }
                else
                {
                    window.location.reload();
                }                   
            }


          return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
      };
    });

}])
```